No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://example.com/accounts}GetAccountRequest]
I have created an API Soap and I receive this error: No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://example.com/accounts}GetAccountRequest]
I do a request test on Postman at url localhost:8082/ws:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                 xmlns:ns="http://example.com/accounts">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <ns:GetAccountRequest>
        <ns:accountId>2</ns:accountId>
     </ns:GetAccountRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

** This is my code endpoint **

@Endpoint
public class AccountEndpoint {

   private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://example.com/accounts";

   private final AccountService accountService;

   public AccountEndpoint(AccountService accountService) {
       this.accountService = accountService;
   }

   @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "GetAccountRequest")
   @ResponsePayload
   public GetAccountResponse getAccount(@RequestPayload GetAccountRequest request) {
       return accountService.getAccount(request);
   }
}

on Postman I use this headers: Content-Type text/xml`

